# ASP.NET is not displaying changes I do to code

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web app I have a lot of gridviews and so on. Now I was trying to change some data format in the gridview, and the changes did not take effect when i debugged, either in Chrome nor Internet Explorer, it kept showing the same gridview as before. I tried to change the SQL data I was providing to it, and it actually changed, so the problem is when I'm altering in my web project.

Wondering what this could be, I did another test by removing the function that triggered when a button is pressed. When I debugged not only I did not get the error that usually comes with not assigning anything to a OnButtonClick but also when I pressed the button it did what it was doing before i removed the function.

Did this already happen to any of you?

Edit1. Now I tried to create an empty webform and when I debugged I get this error:

```
Error of analyzer
Description: Error parsing a resource required to make this request. See the
specific analysis error details below and modify your source file appropriately .
```

Comment: not much any of us can do without seeing existing code and the line(s) of code you are expecting to see the results / changes

Comment: why do you have opening and closing `{ }` for these lines   
`ds.Tables[0].Rows[8][0] = "Average";
        {
            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            gv.DataBind();
        }`

Comment: yeah no need for those, thank you. but the problem was not that, I updated the quesiton with my error.

Comment: did you add it manually or create a new file and all you would need to do is add the MasterPage part.. also what's the MasterPage aspx look like.. why not use the ide to add new item--> webpage and then go from there
for example in my masterpage I have a section declared like this `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />` in my actual web page I would expect to see the following 


`<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">` and it's ending tag
`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting cache and cookies from (both of) your browsers.

Sometimes this gives problems when you are debugging because you will keep seeing previous parts of your current app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting in IIS or debugging with Visual Studio's inbuilt server?

Try cleaning and rebuilding your code, then clearing your browser cache

Comment: I'm debugging with VS inbuilt server. Now I tried to reate a new web form, even if it is empty, and it results in an error: `Error of analyzer` with the error message `Could not load type ' MyProject.Sales.WebForm1 ' .`, where MyProject is my project and webform is in a paste named Sales. I dont understand, even this afternoon I made changes and yesterday I created new web forms.

Comment: @goodie I'm afraid I don't have enough information to help you with that. Vs inbuilt server can be weird

Comment: I had a backup in which my webapp was a bit older, but it was functional. Just created the pages and folders, and copied the code, and it worked, also the changes are being displayed too, it fixed everything (it seems they were correlated of course). I don't know what happened here.

Comment: problem might have been in your project properties